# What is the difference beteween 并 and 和 in sentence (S. V. and V.)?

Tags: difference

What is the difference beteween 并 and 和 in sentence (S. V. and V.)? Which one is correct. E.g.:

> 我们在一起跑步(并/和)参加了铁人三项赛

Comment: basic grammar(likely covered at this site before),  grammar topic:  conjunctions 连词，coordination 并列关系，＂外国实用汉语语法＂：＂ **和**  ＂除了常连接名词、名词性词组和代词外，还可以连接动词、形容词和动词性词组。例如：讨论和通过，巩固和发展（动词），幸福和愉快，勤劳和勇敢（形容词），划船、游泳和爬山（词组），积极恢复和努力发展（词组）＂实用现代汉语语法＂＂ **并**  ，并且＂都是表示递进关系的连词，可以连接两个动词（短语），也可以连接  **分句**  ，＂并且＂还可以连接句子。＂并＂和＂并且＂用在所连接的后一个词或短语等前面。（一）连接两个动词，表示不止进行了一个动作（同时或先后），而且第二个动作比第一个动作更进一步。例如：（１）在昨天的会上，代表们讨论并通过了两项决议。＂讨论＂以后才能＂通过＂，＂通过＂比讨论＂更进一步。（２）而现在语言文字学家真正关心并参与这项工作的不多。。。（二）连接两个动词短语。例如：（１）真理是跟谬误相比较，并且同它作斗争发展起来的。（２）我希望所有的人都去干并且都干好自己爱干的工作，为国家现代化建设做出贡献。（３）今天是老母亲七十整寿，大儿子上礼拜就来了并给了五百块钱。

Comment: （三）  **连接分句** 。例如：（１）这位老大夫十分重视基础医学理论的探讨，并在新的手术设计和改进方面有许多贡献。（２）老师用右手拍了拍阿宝的肩膀，并向他做了个鼓励的手势。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't usually use 并/和 to interpret (S. V. and V.) in English if two actions are not really relevant. Instead, we can use 又...又...

For example,

1. We sing and dance： 我们又唱又跳。 Not 我们唱 并/和 跳.
2. We eat and drink. = 我们又吃又喝。 not 我们吃 并/和 喝.

However, we use 和(not 并) to interpret (S. and S. + V.) and (S + V + O. and O.).

For example,

1. 他和我去买东西。： he and I go shopping.
2. 我吃苹果和香蕉。： I eat apple and banana.

并 is short for 并且, and could be used as conjunction, meaning 'and'. It often connects the two sentences or clauses. It could also connect two verbs if the two actions are logically relevant. (S. + V. and V. + O. )

For example,

1. 我完全赞成并乐于接受这一安排。 I fully agree to the arrangement and take it delightfully. // connecting two clauses.
2. 我赞同并接受这个决定。 I agree and accept the decision. // The two actions are relevant in this case.

In your case, 并 should be used as a conjunction for two clauses.

> 我们在一起跑并参加了铁人三项赛.

Comment: So if you say "I can read and write Chinese but I can't speak and listen.", does it sound awkward to hear "我们读和写，可是不会说汉语"?

Comment: "我们读和写，可是不会说汉语"?  sounds unnatural. In this case, you might have to make a simple sentence for each verb phrase, like 我们能 读（or看懂）中文，也能写中文， 但是不会说，也听不懂。

Comment: Thanks. Any more compact way to express it? Seems that it’s a but too long for a chat.

Comment: Or 中文我们会读，会写，但是不会说。

Answer (score 1):

S V1 并 V2

> 我们在一起跑步(V1)并参加(V2)了铁人三项赛

S V O1 和 O2

> 我们一起参加(V)了跑步(O1)和铁人三项赛(O2)

Comment: Is 跑步 an object here? I assumed it is a verb...

Answer (score 0):

**我们在一起跑并参加了铁人三项赛**

...run and then...

并: plus

A more nature one is:

我们一起跑步并参加了铁人三项赛.

和: need two same sentence structure

我们参加了**跑步(比赛)**和铁人三项赛**.